# Stripe Settings not there . .

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, stripe

CiviCRM 5.24.4/WordPress 5.4

Need to sort out Stripe webhook settings, but Administer>CiviContribute>Stripe Settings just takes me to the main admin page. Nothing there at all.

Anybody know why this might be happening? Or how I should adjust webhooks at Stripe, instead?

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to refresh the cache.

Comment: yep i think this is a regression affecting several other components eg Mosaico that has been dealt with in the 5.24.4 release